# Malformed string IN Default Field

Tags: firebird

I'm trying to migrate a Firebird 2.1 database to 2.5 and an error is occurring in the default field. Which charset should I use?

SET SQL DIALECT 3;

CREATE DATABASE 'F:\Sistemas\mga\DataBase\CRIAR.GDB'
USER 'SYSDBA' PASSWORD 'masterkey'
PAGE_SIZE 16384
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET NONE;

CREATE TABLE ESTOQUE (
    ID               INTEGER,
    FORNECEDOR_ID    INTEGER,
    FUNCIONARIOS_ID  INTEGER,
    ID_TABELA        INTEGER,
    DATA             DATE,
    QUANTIDADE       NUMERIC(15,2),
    VALOR_UNITARIO   NUMERIC(15,5) DEFAULT 0,
    TABELA           VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET NONE,
    SAFRA_ID         NUMERIC(18,0),
    VALOR_TOTAL      NUMERIC(15,2),
    TIPO             VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET NONE,
    PROPRIEDADE_ID   INTEGER,
    PLACAS           VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET NONE,
    NOTAS            VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET NONE,
    MOTORISTA        VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET NONE,
    BLOQUEADO        VARCHAR(3) CHARACTER SET NONE DEFAULT 'NÃO',
    DESCRICAO        BLOB SUB_TYPE 1 SEGMENT SIZE 80 CHARACTER SET NONE,
    FRETE            NUMERIC(15,2)
);

Error ::  BLOQUEADO        VARCHAR(3) CHARACTER SET NONE DEFAULT 'NÃO',

```
This operation is not defined for system tables.
unsuccessful metadata update.
STORE RDB$RELATION_FIELDS failed.
Malformed string.
```

I TRY:

```
SET NAMES WIN1252;
WIN1252
CHARACTER SET WIN1252,
CHARACTER SET ISO8859_1
COLLATE PT_BR
```

but, THIS IS OK

```
update ESTOQUE set BLOQUEADO='NÃO' ;
```

Comment: Why not `UTF8`?

Answer (score 0):

Backup database and try to restore with these options:

```
 c:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_2_5\bin\gbak.exe -R O c:\temp\my_backup.FBK my_new_database.fdb 
 -FIX_FSS_M WIN1252 -FIX_FSS_D WIN1252 -USER SYSDBA -PAS masterkey -V
```

Comment: And that needs reading and understanding the relevant part of the documentation (at least RelNotes) of FB 2.5 because FIX METADATA options are potentially harmful.